# How to extract substr following the matching value

Tags: regex

I have the following string, from which I want to extract the value of the `key2` which is `value2`

```
[key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3]
```

I tried giving the following regex `,key2=(.*),\w+`but it is extracting `,key2=value2,key3`but I am want only the value `value2`

What regex can be used for this one?

Comment: You already captured the value you need, it is in Group 1. What tool/programming language are you using?

Comment: your answer is in group1, you should use the regex  
key2=(\w+)

Comment: If you use 'key2=(.*),' , you result is 'key2=value2'. I think you should substring the result to get the result that you want. Regards,

Comment: As answered above, your result is in group 1. How to retrieve it depends on the language/tool you're using. I'd also advise you to use `,key2=(.*?),\w+` to make sure you don't capture more than you need. `?` means you want the shortest string that matches.

Comment: `(.*?),\w+` will not match the *shortest* string, but up to the leftmost occurrence of `,\w+` subpattern. I.e. if there are multiple `,key2=` in the string, the match will include its first occurrence and then all up to the first `,\w+=`. That is why the best regex here is `(?:,|^)key2=(\w*)`, or - if there is no way to grab Group 1 value, there are options like `(?:,|^)key2=\K\w*` or `(?<=,key2=)\w*`.

Comment: Hi guys, If I try `(?:,|^)key2=(\w*)` or key2=(\w+) in regexr.com, the whole of the `,key2=value2` is getting highlighted. I was expecting only the capturing group with value `value2` to be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

With a lookbehind you should solve the problem:

```
(?<=(?:key2=))\w+
```